# Dispatch call to main queue inside UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, uibackgroundtask

I am running a certain task under `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` since i want to run it in background. My code looks something like this.

```
-(void) function
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier BGIdentifier = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{}];     

        // some processing

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // some UI stuff
        });

        // some processing again

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // some UI stuff again
        });

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:BGIdentifier];        
    });
}
```

So I have two questions.

1. If my app goes to background while some processing is happening what will happen to the dispatch_async calls to main queue?
2. Is this a good design ?

Comment: Thanks Rob for pointing that out. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your question, those dispatched blocks to the main queue operate as you'd expect, and everything will work fine, and when the app is brought back into the foreground, you'll see the UI updated properly. Two caveats:

1. You will want to ensure that the `endBackgroundTask` is not invoked before the final dispatch is done. You can achieve this by either:

   - Make that final UI dispatch synchronous; or
   - Include the `endBackgroundTask` as the last item in the last block you dispatch to the main queue.

   But the timing of this `endBackgroundTask` is important, you want to make sure you update your UI before you flag your background task as complete and indicate that it may be suspended.
2. I don't know how you want to handle a failure to complete the background task, but generally you would call `endBackgroundTask` in the expiration handler, too, because otherwise the app will be summarily terminated if the background task didn't complete in the allotted time. See the [Executing a Finite-Length Task in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW28) of the *App States and Multitasking* chapter of the *iOS App Programming Guide* for an example.

Comment: Instead of dispatching synchronously, he should call the `endBackgroundTask` in the last of those blocks dispatched to the main thread.

Comment: @newacct That works, too. I personally prefer the symmetry of my approach (ending the task on the same thread that created it; only dispatching stuff to the main queue that require the main queue; etc.), but I understand the appeal of your approach, too, so I've revised my answer to include that option (I actually had it there when I first drafted the answer, but thought I was throwing too many options out there; lol).